# How to call asp.net wepapi from Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created android application to send push notification. I am getting the device registration ID in Java code, from that how to send the registration ID to the asp.net webapi. The following is the webapi method.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void SendPushNotification(string deviceRegID, string notificationMessage)
    {
        AndroidGCMPushNotification apnGCM = new AndroidGCMPushNotification();            
        string strResponse = apnGCM.NotifyTest(deviceTokenID, notificationMessage);
    }
```

I am calling this webapi as **"http://www.example.com:80/sendPushNotification/deviceRegID/notificationMessage"** (example.com:80 is the ipaddress and port) from the browser, it's being triggered. How can I call this from Android mainactivity.

Comment: Hi,Anybody there to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and execute a normal HTTP request from Android. You can take a look at this question for details: [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Of course if you are hosting the WebAPI application on your local machine, you have to make sure that the URL is accessible from the emulator/device on which you are running the Android application.